# Get RealmResults list inside object android

Tags: android, realm

Sorry for my english. I have adapter `extends RealmBaseAdapter` for auto update listview. And i have object

**People**

```
String id;
String name;
RealmList<Dog> dogs;
```

**Dog**

```
String id;
String name;
```

I need by `id` People get dogs list. I cant undestand how do this.

I do like this

```
RealmResults<People> realmQuery = realm
                    .where(People.class)
                    .equalTo("id", "myId")
                    .findAll();
```

but now i get only one people, but i need get `RealmResults` **dog**.

Comment: You need the dogs that belong to the user? Like `realmQuery.get(0).getDogs`?

Comment: @TimCastelijns yes, i need get RealmResult dogs for each people

Comment: Where do you need it? In the adapter?

Comment: @TimCastelijns i need it for adapter. My adapter `extends RealmBaseAdapter` and for constructor that need `RealmResults<Dog>` for auto update list

Comment: So you are displaying only the dogs of the users in the list? Not the users themself

Comment: @TimCastelijns i have list users, when click for some user i need output in new list, list dogs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the onClick handler when you press on a user, do

```
RealmResult<Dog> realmResults = user.getDogs().where().findAll();
```

You can query a RealmList. By saying `where()` you say "give me all of them". And it gives you a RealmResult.